# Some processes high CPU usage in Windows 10

Tags: drivers, process, cpu-usage, windows-10

I installed Windows 10 and all the driver (BIOS included) from Dell site; luckily my laptop is Windows 10 compatible.

2 processes use a little too CPU, I'm talking about "System" and "Windows desktop manager".

When the laptop is not in use these 2 processes eat 4/5% CPU.

I tried to do a safe boot mode and the situation changes since CPU usage is 0%.

Anyone has the same problem or knows how to solve it?

[image]

Comment: capture a xperf trace of the cpu usage in normal mode, a 2nd in safe mode and share the compressed ETL files: http://pastebin.com/pgE11HRD

Comment: Thank you for the reply. This procedure maybe it's too complicated for me. I tinkered with Microsoft Process Explorer Tool and I find that Realtek Audio Driver eats too CPU. I uninstalled it and the CPU usage decreased but now I'm without audio and the audiodg.exe process that eats too CPU.  Another process that eats too CPU is procexp64.exe but it's a system process so I assume I can not do nothing?

Comment: enable the driver again and disable the audio enhancements in the media options. this can also reduce the CPU usage.